# ssh fails to start due to missing host keys

Tags: openssh, sshd

While trying to start an ssh server daemon I get an error about missing hostkeys, however, looking at `/etc/ssh` I see the host keys are there and I believe the permissions are correct.

This is with OpenSSH 8.3p1 on an embedded Linux system.

Any ideas on what is wrong with my OpenSSH configuration?

```
~> ls -l /etc/ssh
total 529
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        525809 Mar 30 15:16 moduli
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1484 Mar 30 15:16 ssh_config
-rw-------    1 root     root          1369 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           600 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root     root           505 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           172 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root     root           399 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            92 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root     root          2590 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           564 Mar 30 19:02 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2333 Mar 30 17:29 sshd_config
~> systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-30 19:02:43 UTC; 8s ago
    Process: 338 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 465 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D -e (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 465 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 30 19:02:41 cm1sd ssh-keygen[338]: ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
Mar 30 19:02:41 cm1sd systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Mar 30 19:02:43 cm1sd sshd[465]: sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
Mar 30 19:02:43 cm1sd systemd[1]: sshd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 19:02:43 cm1sd systemd[1]: sshd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Edit:**

The config does include the HostKey

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

**Edit 2:**

I've updated to OpenSSH 8.5p1 and ran with debugging enabled and get some additional info:

```
~> sshd -D -e -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 374
debug2: parse_server_config_depth: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 374
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:14 setting Port 10505
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:19 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:35 setting MaxAuthTries 6
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:36 setting MaxSessions 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:38 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:42 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:55 setting IgnoreRhosts yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:58 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:59 setting PermitEmptyPasswords no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:67 setting X11Forwarding no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:89 setting Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
Unable to load host key "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key": error in libcrypto
Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

Looks like the issue is with OpenSSL's libcrypto. I have OpenSSL version 1.1.1k installed.

Comment: Is `HostKey` set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: @Wieland, yes, HostKey is set

Comment: And if you try starting the service _again_, now that the keys are generated?

Comment: Try:       dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server; systemctl restart ssh; systemctl status ssh

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've tried starting the service multiple times after the keys are generated, same result.

Comment: @CinaedSimson, This is an embedded Linux system, dpkg is not available. The system is built via Buildroot.

Comment: Okay, try this URL https://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/HowToRegenerateNewSsh.

Comment: @CinaedSimson, No luck. This creates the host keys just like `ssh-keygen -A`. I get the same error regardless of which way the host keys were generated.

Answer (score 18):

On WSL, this worked:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -A
sudo service ssh --full-restart
```

Comment: works for me... Thank you

Comment: With termux, this worked and also following this [article](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/sshd-no-hostkeys-available-exiting.html) helped too!